# File descriptor redirection difference

Tags: bash

Why `>file 2>&1` works but `2>&1 >file` doesn't? BTW there is no syntax error.

Comment: You may find the answers here helpful: [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections)

Comment: "BTW there is no syntax error." because it is syntactically correct but is unlikely to be intended. Use `2>&1 | tee file1` ;)